# Backup SharePoint Content Database and Restore on other Farm using Powershell

Tags: shell, powershell, sharepoint, powershell-2.0, sharepoint-2013

HeyHo,

I want to know if it is possible to write a script to BackUp a SharePoint 2013 Content Database on a Test Farm and Restore it on the Dev Farm (uses another instance of a SQL-Cluster) running only 1 script on the Test Farm.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hmm, it's not as easy as I've initially thought. You can do `New-PSSession` vs destination farm, but you might not be able to run `Restore-SPFarm` against destination farm from that session. you can, however, do a remote script execution trick with `Start-Process` that'll run in the destination farm context.